# WCF service without using proxy in C#

Tags: c#, wcf

I have got a WCF service from one of my users. I want to check whether the service is working or not without adding any proxy. Is there any way that I can achieve this in my C# code?

Comment: Use ChannelFactory<T>. You will need access to the service assemblies to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this by implementing an endpoint at WCF and querying it from the client.
Following is the WCF code I would use.

```
// Used for communication between WCF and client. Must be implemented both WCF and client sides
public class Response {
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Data { get; set; }
}

// Web Service - Interface
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
      [OperationContract]
      [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "Up")]
      string CheckLogin();
}

// Web service - Implementation
public class ServiceImplementation : IService
{
  public Response isUp()
  {
         Response response = new Response();
         response.ID = 200;
         response.Data = "web service is up";
         return response;
  }
}
```

Following is the client method to test if the service is up.

```
public bool CheckIfUp(string encodedUrl)
{
     WebRequest request;
     WebResponse ws;
     Response response = new Response();
     string url = "http://servicePath/isUp"; // your wcf url
     try
       {
                request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                ws = request.GetResponse();
                return (response.ID == 200);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
                Console.Write(e.StackTrace);
       }
            return false;
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i don't have the access to the WCF service code. I have got only only the service url.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending `?wsdl` at the of the URL pointing to the WCF-service.

If your Web service address is

```
http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx
```

you can reach your wsdl file like this:

```
http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx?WSDL
```

The returned WSDL allows you to see all the method the WCF-service provides.